# Good coding theory books?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, coding-theory

Next week starts my coding theory course and I am really looking forward to it.

Can anybody suggest to me good coding theory books? I've already taken a cryptography class last semester and I studied it with *Handbook of Applied Cryptography* by Alfred J. Menezes; I found it very useful. Is there a coding theory book like this with many examples?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Usually the course tells you the required/recommended bibliography. Examples: MacKay (Information theory...), Lin Costello (Error control coding), Moreira-Farrel (Essentials of error-control coding), Neubauer-et-al (Coding theory), Richardson (Modern coding theory)

Answer (score 7):

Macwilliams and Sloane's The Theory of Error-Correcting Codes is excellent though its about 40 years old at this point, but everyone who is serious about coding theory needs to own this book.

A book I quite like that's more recent is R.M. Roth's Introduction to Coding Theory -- has a bit of a CS flavor to the approach. For engineering (esp. applications), I think Error correction coding by Moon is good.

For LDPC codes and the like, Richardson's Modern coding theory or Mackay's information theory book are good points to start from.

Answer (score 2):

I took a course last spring that was an introduction to Coding Theory and this was the textbook:

"A  First   Course  in  Coding  Theory"
*By: Raymond    Hill*

It was a nice taste of single-error correcting codes and provided a strong foundation from which to build on.  In addition, if you are looking for a book with many examples, this textbook has exercises at the end of every chapter and has answers to EVERY exercise in the back of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's been a while since the last comment, it's worth suggesting the pretty recently updated book [Essential Coding Theory](https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/) by Guruswami, Rudra, and Sudan.

I think it has a reasonable amount of information for a beginner, and is written in an approachable way.