# Error Correction Codes - Book Recommendation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, coding-theory

Could you, please, recommend me a well written book, with plenty of examples and exercises and suitable for self study in Error Correction Codes, which includes the following topics?

> **Hamming Distance 0 Perfect Codes - Equivalent Codes - Linear Codes - Generator Matrices - Encoding - Parity Check Matrices - Decoding a
>   Linear Code - Majority Logic Decoding - Weight Enumerator - Shannon's
>   Theorem - Lower Bounds of Codes - Singleton's Bound - MDS Codes -
>   Plotkin's Bound - Griesmer's Bound - Hamming Codes - Golay Codes -
>   Reed-Muller Codes**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can check the one on "Error control coding" by Shu Lin, Daniel J. Costello.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I ll check it!

Comment: For the Shannon theorem(s), there's the classic Cover & Thomas. For ECC: "Ryan & Lin" and "Moreira & Farrel" are pretty comprehensive. "Lin & Costello" is more detailed, only for "classic coding". "Richardson & Urbanke", only for "modern coding". MacKay (Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms) for more ample perspectives.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: There's a great online book by Guruswami, Rudra and Sudan [here](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/)

Comment: @Parzan Thank you for your comment. It seems to be a good book, but I think I doesn't have many examples.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by numerous comments, including those by [Nash J.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/439920/nash-j), [leonbloy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/312/leonbloy), and [Parzan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/157484/parzan).

I will add that there are also additional posts containing references for error correcting codes, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926649/good-coding-theory-books/4848962#4848962) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/a-book-in-coding-theory). (So maybe this should be marked as a duplicate, but I'll leave that to more seasoned MathSE users).

From the comments:

1. From Nash J., "You can check the one on "Error control coding" by Shu Lin, Daniel J. Costello."
2. From leonbloy, "For the Shannon theorem(s), there's the classic Cover & Thomas. For ECC: "Ryan & Lin" and "Moreira & Farrel" are pretty comprehensive. "Lin & Costello" is more detailed, only for "classic coding". "Richardson & Urbanke", only for "modern coding". MacKay (Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms) for more ample perspectives."
3. From Parzan, "There's a great online book by Guruswami, Rudra and Sudan [here](https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/)"